# I heard a word that sounded like psycho in English, what does it mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

The person that said it was very animated and happy, but it sounded exactly like the word psycho. Thank you.

Comment: I have seen サイコパス（Saikopasu) for psychopath but never サイコ(saiko) alone. Definitely istrasci answer!

Comment: If I'm not very much mistaken, Saiko is a fairly common name in anime, if not in real life.  Are you sure the one who spoke wasn't calling someone's name?

Comment: @Steve-O I don't think are that many 'Saiko's, even in anime.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[最高]{さい・こう} means "the highest/maximum/best/greatest".

Answer (score 7):

最{さい}高{こう}, or sometimes stylized　サイコー, particularly as an interjection, is an expression of how fun / cool / enjoyable something is -- as was the case in your question.

However, as istrasci pointed out, in itself 最{さい}高{こう} means the superlative of some state. 

Some examples:
最{さい}高{こう}級{きゅう} -- Highest grade / class / rank. 
最{さい}高{こう}経{けい}営{えい}責{せき}任{にん}者{しゃ} -- Chief Executive Officer (literally the "highest person responsible for business administration").

Answer (score 4):

最高(さいこう) is used exactly like "awesome" is used in American English. It is mostly used in spoken language, rarely in written language.